# jQuery Hover one element at a time when nested

Tags: jquery, hover, addclass

I'm using jquery to add a hover class to certain elements in an html document. That works just fine, however if an element that is hover-able has a child that is hover-able, both get the hover class even though currently mouse is only over the child element.

How can I avoid that?

```
<div class="hoverable">
  text/html content
  <div class="hoverable"> tect/html content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where your jQuery code stuff??

Comment: Please add some jQuery code that you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent event propagation in your event handler function.

```
$('.hoverable').hover(function(event) {

    // Adding CSS class to the hovered element.
    $(this).addClass('hovered');

    // Preventing event propagation by calling stopPropagation()...
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Or by returning false.
    return false;

}, function(event) {

    // Removing CSS class from the hovered element.
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');

    // Preventing event propagation by calling stopPropagation()...
    event.stopPropagation();

    // Or by returning false.
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well... we're missing some context. However, let's see if we what we can do...

I assume that you cannot do the easiest thing and set separate hover classes. That is...

```
<div class="hoverable-a">
  text/html content
  <div class="hoverable-b"> text/html content </div>
</div>
```

I assume that you're doing something like...

```
$(".hoverable").hover(function() { ... });
```

The above will select everything with class `hoverable` as in your example. There are a couple of approaches here. Within the hover function `function() { ... }`, you could add...

(1) Find if the the direct parent also has class `hoverable`, if so skip it

```
if ($(this).parent().is(".hoverable"))
  return;
```

and similar

```
if ($(this).closest(".hoverable").length > 0)
  return;
```

(2) If each parent element contains children hoverable elements, then make sure there are no children

if ($(this).children(".hoverable") != 0)
     return;

(3) I'm sure there are other solutions. It depends on your exact structure :)